# Iterate over snapshot children in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, nsenumerator

I have a Firebase resource that contains several objects and I would like to iterate over them using Swift.
What I expected to work is the following (according to the Firebase documentation)
https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/FDataSnapshot.html#//api/name/children

```
var ref = Firebase(url:MY_FIREBASE_URL)
ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
  println(snapshot.childrenCount) // I got the expected number of items
    for rest in snapshot.children { //ERROR: "NSEnumerator" does not have a member named "Generator"
       println(rest.value)     
     }
 })
```

So it seems there is a problem with Swift iterating over the NSEnumerator object returned by Firebase.

Help is really welcome.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

If I read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDataSnapshot#children) right, this is what you want:

```
var ref = Firebase(url: MY_FIREBASE_URL)
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
    print(snapshot.childrenCount) // I got the expected number of items
    for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
       print(rest.value)     
    }
}
```

A better way might be:

```
var ref = Firebase(url: MY_FIREBASE_URL)
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
    print(snapshot.childrenCount) // I got the expected number of items
    let enumerator = snapshot.children
    while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
       print(rest.value)     
    }
}
```

The first method requires the `NSEnumerator` to return an array of all of the objects which can then be enumerated in the usual way.  The second method gets the objects one at a time from the `NSEnumerator` and is likely more efficient.

In either case, the objects being enumerated are `FIRDataSnapshot` objects, so you need the casts so that you can access the `value` property.

---

**Using `for-in` loop:**

Since writing the original answer back in Swift 1.2 days, the language has evolved.  It is now possible to use a `for in` loop which works directly with enumerators along with `case let` to assign the type:

```
var ref = Firebase(url: MY_FIREBASE_URL)
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
    print(snapshot.childrenCount) // I got the expected number of items
    for case let rest as FIRDataSnapshot in snapshot.children {
       print(rest.value)     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

I have just converted the above answer to **Swift 3:**

```
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()    
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
       print(snapshot.childrenCount) // I got the expected number of items
       for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
           print(rest.value)
           }
})
```

A better way might be:

```
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference() 
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.childrenCount) // I got the expected number of items
            let enumerator = snapshot.children
            while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                print(rest.value)
            }
        })
```

Comment: Thanks it works but `print(rest.value)` prints `Optional(0)` instead it should be printing a interger. How can i make `print(rest.value)` to print a integer?

Answer (score 16):

This is pretty readable and works fine:

```
var ref = Firebase(url:MY_FIREBASE_URL)
ref.childByAppendingPath("some-child").observeSingleEventOfType(
  FEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in

      for child in snapshot.children {

        let childSnapshot = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath(child.key)
        let someValue = childSnapshot.value["key"] as! String
      }
})
```

Comment: and if i want to remove the someValue from firebase database just that key, what i do?

Comment: for SDK v2, do we have anyway to make a promise callback in forloop make sure we done all the stuffs before doing other things

Comment: There is no reason to call `childSnapshotForPath`, each child is already a child snapshot.

Answer (score 8):

```
   ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("exampleUsernames")    
   ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

       for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {

           guard let restDict = rest.value as? [String: Any] else { continue }
           let username = restDict["username"] as? String
       }
   })
```

Answer (score 6):

**Firebase** 4.0.1

```
       Database.database().reference().child("key").observe(.value) { snapshot in
            if let datas = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                let results = datas.flatMap({
                  ($0.value as! [String: Any])["xxx"]
                })
                print(results)
            }
       }
```

**Firebase** 7.3.0

```
       Database.database().reference().child("key").observe(.value) { snapshot in
            if let datas = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                let results = datas.compactMap({
                  ($0.value)
                })
                print(results)
            }
       }
```

If you have multiple keys/values, and want to `return` an `array` with `dictionary` elements, declare an array:

```
var yourArray = [[String: Any]]()
```

then change block body to this:

```
     let children = snapshot.children
     while let rest = children.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot, let value = rest.value {
          self.yourArray.append(value as! [String: Any])
      }
```