# What kind of object is the following output?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

What kind of object is the output of firebase data? Here is the code to output it (from [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html#section-getting-data)):

```
myRootRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
  snapshot in
  println("\(snapshot.value)")
})
```

Here is the output:

```
{
    a =     {
        FirstName = "";
        LastName = "";
    };
    b =     {
        FirstName = "";
        LastName = "";
    };
    c =     {
        FirstName = "";
        LastName = "";
    };
}
```

What object is that? (`Array`, `Dictionary`, `String`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an [`FDataSnapshot`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/FDataSnapshot.html). Since Firebase is a NoSQL/JSON data store, it serializes these snapshots to a pseudo-JSON structure when you print them. But when you need to get primitive values out of a snapshot, use the methods of `FDataSnapshot` like `childSnapshotForPath:` until you reach a simple property (`FirstName` and `LastName` in your sample) and then `value` to get the primitive value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How would I iterate through the data with a for loop?

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/FDataSnapshot.html#//api/name/children, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341888/iterate-over-snapshot-children-in-swift-firebase and the last example here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/structuring-data.html#section-indices

Comment: Thanks! I tried this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341888/iterate-over-snapshot-children-in-swift-firebase#answer-27342233. When I output it to the console, this is what I get: 
{
        FirstName = "";
        LastName = "";
};
How can I get "FirstName" as a string

Comment: `snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("FirstName").value`

Answer (score 1):

It is a Dictionary of type `[String: AnyObject]`

**UPDATE to comment**

It is a Dictionary with Key of Type String, which values are Dictionarys with key String and Value String.... So to be exactly

```
[String: [String: String]]
```

Comment: Is it nested? because there are 4 diff things. 1: 'a' 2: 'FirstName = ""';  3: 'LastName = "";'