# querying messages in firebase using swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have to query the messages for the current user . I am using the same format(flat structure) as suggested by firebase documents.

[messages structure](https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/data)

the only difference is i am using room id combination generated from parse for the room which i can access(not one,two given in the link above) [image: me]

Now this is the code I have written to get the messages for sender :

```
messagesRef.childByAppendingPath(roomid).queryOrderedByChild("sender").queryEqualToValue(senderuserName)
    .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { messageTextsnapshot in

print("messageTextsnapshot test is \(messageTextsnapshot.key) , \(messageTextsnapshot.value)")
    })
```

this prints

```
messageTextsnapshot test is B8qLq7esr0L4Ezen0owHQ7PfdpD077lLfCswolf , {
    "-K8v2sM7VL_xvfbmWMom" =     {
        message = Hmm;
        sender = B8qLq7esr0L4Ezen0owHQ7Pfd;
        timestamp = "[.sv: timestamp]";
    };
    "-K8v3cv9EGqZlXSF4fGB" =     {
        message = Up;
        sender = B8qLq7esr0L4Ezen0owHQ7Pfd;
        timestamp = "[.sv: timestamp]";
    };
}
```

which are the correct messages. but how do i access them. I have been stuck since last 3 hours. I have this problem since i dont know how to query when auto ID's are involved. What should be the query to drill down to the messages.

Comment: You're getting a value that contains multiple children, so you need to loop over those children. See this question for how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341888/iterate-over-snapshot-children-in-swift-firebase

Comment: I will check this tomo and update. Thanks!

Comment: thank you that worked. You can put it in answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: Great to hear that it worked. Accepting an answer it not necessary, I marked your question as a duplicate of the one I linked you to.