# sorting doesnt work with queryOrdered in firebase realtime database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
  "users":{
    "steve_rodriquez":{
        "ch1":{
             "timestamp":2
        },
        "ch2":{
            "timestamp":1
        },
        "ch3":{
            "timestamp":4
        },
        "ch4":{
            "timestamp":3
        }
    }   
}
```

Rules are defined as

```
 "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "users":{
         ".indexOn": ["timestamp"] 
    }
  }
```

When i try to sort based on time stamp it doesnt work. i added  1,2,3,4 just for example

This is my client side code for it

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
        (ref.child("users").child("steve_rodriquez")).queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
            print(snapshot.value as Any)
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you retrieve the data from Firebase, the snapshot contains the keys, the values, **and** the order of all child nodes. But when you call `snapshot.value` it needs to convert this to a `Dictionary`, which only has space for the keys and the values. So at this point the information about the order of the child nodes is lost.

To maintain the order of the child nodes, iterate over the `snapshot.children` as shown in the documentation on [listening for child events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events), and for example this answer: [Iterate over snapshot children in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341888/iterate-over-snapshot-children-in-firebase)

Comment: Thanks! that works. Just another question when i delete the index from the rules the query order still works. Do i really need to define the rules ?

Comment: If you don't define an index, the ordering/filtering will be done client-side. So all data at the location will be downloaded to the client, and then ordered/filtered there. If you're only ordering this is just a bit slower. But if you're also filtering, you'll be wasting bandwidth this way.

Comment: thanks! So lets say i define the index in the rules and i order it by timestamp and also limit the result to 10 and implement pagination. Would it still be getting the entire result to the client side and order and then return the 10 results or would it only be bringing those 10 results to the client(saving bandwidth)?

Comment: If you don't have an index, all data at the location will be downloaded to the client.